# Logistic Regression : fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```
#importing modules
import pandas as pd
import sys,time,math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression as LR
print('modules imported')

#Reading the files
l_file = pd.read_csv('home_data.csv')
l_file
l_file.describe()

#scatter plot between square feet and price
plt.scatter(l_file['sqft_living'], l_file['price'],c='#637691')

#Splitting the data into train(20%) and test(80%)
test, train = tts(l_file,test_size = 0.8,random_state = 20, shuffle=True)

#Dividing into target and indent
def xAndy(f_data):
    f_indent = f_data.drop(['price'], axis=1 )
    f_target = f_data['price']
    return f_indent, f_target

#Splitting in x and y
x_train ,y_train = xAndy(train)

l_model = LR
l_model.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

I am trying to predict the price of a house using Linear Regression Model. I am encountering an error in this step **l_model.fit(x_train, y_train)**.
Please suggest how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: try `l_model = LR()`

Answer (score 1):

The model declaration needs parantacies.

```
l_model = LR()
```

This should do it.

Comment: No, it doesnt resolve. Now, it gives and value error
''' could not convert string to float: '20150323T000000'''

Comment: that is a different problem. Does the errormessage tell you in which line the error appears? It seems like you have a timestap column, which cant be read easily. There are tons of questions on here on how to handle it. Easiest way in my experience is transforming to datetime while your still handling the dataframe. And depending on you exact problem having one column per timeinterval (e.g. year, month, day, hour,...)

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth pointing out why the fix given in a comment and in another answer works, and why it doesn't appear at first glance to have anything to do with the error message.

Setting `l_model = LR` (without parentheses) is giving `l_model` as *the class* `LinearRegression`, **not** an *instance* of the class.  Now `fit` is a method of the class, so `l_model.fit(...)` can be called.  Now, training the model will fail eventually because you're missing required attributes from `__init__`, which gets called when you make an instance of the class.  But it doesn't even get that far, because the signature for `fit` is `(self, X, y)`; because you have not initialized, `self` doesn't get exist or get passed in, so python is taking `self=x_train`, `X=y_train`, and `y` is missing, and hence the error message.